# Java, HttpClient issue (android)

Tags: java, android, httpclient

Past few hours I have been working on this without any luck.

```
    public void OnClickEventOnButton(View view)
{
    this.commonContext = new BasicHttpContext(); //defined in the class to acihive 
    HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get=new HttpGet("http://somesite.com");

    HttpResponse response=null;
    try{
        response=httpClient.execute(get);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
        }           
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        alert(e.toString(),"エラ");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        alert("HTTPHelp : IOException : "+e,"エラ");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){
        alert("Null pointer : "+e.getCause(), "sfasfd");

    }
}
```

The line below where my exception is generating

```
response=httpClient.execute(get);
```

The error my device showing is `Unfortunately, Data Retriver has stopped.`

If you need any more information, please let me know. If you need any specific data, please guide me, just started learning, I will provide the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but do you

a) don't have the `INTERNET` permission added in your manifest?
- this means you should see a "`IllegalStateException`" in your logcat

b) you execute Network on the applications main thread?
- this means you should see a "`NetworkOnMainthreadException` in your logcat

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer actually informed me a whole new thing. I have been studying android for past 3 days and was stuck entire yesterday night without any clue of permission issue. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! But keep in mind to look for Exceptions in your logcat and add them to your question if you ask them on SO. Often they tell you exactly whats going wrong, or provide useful informations for people trying to answer your question.